# maven cobertura reports 0% with aspectj

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, aspectj, cobertura

Has anyone been able to use maven2 with the Aspectj plugin, and Cobertura plugin? I keep getting 0% coverage, when I should get something. Cobertura instrumentation is running before Aspectj weaving which, I think, is messing up the Cobertura instrumentation. Also, Cobertura is giving warnings about my aspects, it looks like it is trying to parse them as java files. Any help would be appreciated.

```
C:\project>mvn cobertura:cobertura
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Project
[INFO]    task-segment: [cobertura:cobertura]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Preparing cobertura:cobertura
[INFO] [aspectj:compile {execution: compile}]
[INFO] [resources:resources]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] [compiler:compile]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [cobertura:instrument]
[INFO] Cobertura 1.9.2 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
Cobertura: Loaded information on 538 classes.
Instrumenting 538 files to C:\project\target\generated-classes\cobertura
Cobertura: Saved information on 538 classes.
Instrument time: 3938ms

[INFO] Instrumentation was successful.
[INFO] [aspectj:test-compile {execution: test-compile}]
[INFO] [resources:testResources]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [surefire:test]
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\project\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running project.AnnounceTypeActionTest

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.594 sec

Results :

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] [cobertura:cobertura]
[INFO] Cobertura 1.9.2 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
Cobertura: Loaded information on 538 classes.
Javancss.(InputStream).e: net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.ParseException: Encountered "aspect" at line 5, column 8.
Was expecting one of:
    "@" ...
    "abstract" ...
    "final" ...
    "public" ...
    "synchronized" ...
    "strictfp" ...
    "class" ...
    "static" ...
    "protected" ...
    "private" ...
    "native" ...
    "transient" ...
    "volatile" ...
    "enum" ...
    "interface" ...

[cobertura] WARN  [main] net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.ComplexityCalculator - JavaNCSS got an error while parsing the java file C:\project\src\main\java\Project\logging\ApplicationLoggingAspect.aj
ParseException in STDIN
Last useful checkpoint: "project.logging."
Encountered "aspect" at line 5, column 8.
Was expecting one of:
    "@" ...
    "abstract" ...
    "final" ...
    "public" ...
    "synchronized" ...
    "strictfp" ...
    "class" ...
    "static" ...
    "protected" ...
    "private" ...
    "native" ...
    "transient" ...
    "volatile" ...
    "enum" ...
    "interface" ...


Javancss.(InputStream).e: net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.ParseException: Encountered "aspect" at line 4, column 17.
Was expecting one of:
    "@" ...
    "abstract" ...
    "final" ...
    "public" ...
    "synchronized" ...
    "strictfp" ...
    "class" ...
    "static" ...
    "protected" ...
    "private" ...
    "native" ...
    "transient" ...
    "volatile" ...
    "enum" ...
    "interface" ...

[cobertura] WARN  [main] net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.ComplexityCalculator - JavaNCSS got an error while parsing the java file C:\project\src\main\java\Project\logging\LoggingAspect.aj
ParseException in STDIN
Last useful checkpoint: "project.logging."
Encountered "aspect" at line 4, column 17.
Was expecting one of:
    "@" ...
    "abstract" ...
    "final" ...
    "public" ...
    "synchronized" ...
    "strictfp" ...
    "class" ...
    "static" ...
    "protected" ...
    "private" ...
    "native" ...
    "transient" ...
    "volatile" ...
    "enum" ...
    "interface" ...


Javancss.(InputStream).e: net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.ParseException: Encountered "aspect" at line 6, column 17.
Was expecting one of:
    "@" ...
    "abstract" ...
    "final" ...
    "public" ...
    "synchronized" ...
    "strictfp" ...
    "class" ...
    "static" ...
    "protected" ...
    "private" ...
    "native" ...
    "transient" ...
    "volatile" ...
    "enum" ...
    "interface" ...

[cobertura] WARN  [main] net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.ComplexityCalculator - JavaNCSS got an error while parsing the java file C:\project\src\main\java\Project\logging\TracingAspect.aj
ParseException in STDIN
Last useful checkpoint: "project.logging."
Encountered "aspect" at line 6, column 17.
Was expecting one of:
    "@" ...
    "abstract" ...
    "final" ...
    "public" ...
    "synchronized" ...
    "strictfp" ...
    "class" ...
    "static" ...
    "protected" ...
    "private" ...
    "native" ...
    "transient" ...
    "volatile" ...
    "enum" ...
    "interface" ...


Report time: 5891ms

[INFO] Cobertura Report generation was successful.
[INFO] Cobertura 1.9.2 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
Cobertura: Loaded information on 538 classes.
Javancss.(InputStream).e: net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.ParseException: Encountered "aspect" at line 5, column 8.
Was expecting one of:
    "@" ...
    "abstract" ...
    "final" ...
    "public" ...
    "synchronized" ...
    "strictfp" ...
    "class" ...
    "static" ...
    "protected" ...
    "private" ...
    "native" ...
    "transient" ...
    "volatile" ...
    "enum" ...
    "interface" ...

[cobertura] WARN  [main] net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.ComplexityCalculator - JavaNCSS got an error while parsing the java file C:\project\src\main\java\Project\logging\ApplicationLoggingAspect.aj
ParseException in STDIN
Last useful checkpoint: "project.logging."
Encountered "aspect" at line 5, column 8.
Was expecting one of:
    "@" ...
    "abstract" ...
    "final" ...
    "public" ...
    "synchronized" ...
    "strictfp" ...
    "class" ...
    "static" ...
    "protected" ...
    "private" ...
    "native" ...
    "transient" ...
    "volatile" ...
    "enum" ...
    "interface" ...


Javancss.(InputStream).e: net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.ParseException: Encountered "aspect" at line 4, column 17.
Was expecting one of:
    "@" ...
    "abstract" ...
    "final" ...
    "public" ...
    "synchronized" ...
    "strictfp" ...
    "class" ...
    "static" ...
    "protected" ...
    "private" ...
    "native" ...
    "transient" ...
    "volatile" ...
    "enum" ...
    "interface" ...

[cobertura] WARN  [main] net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.ComplexityCalculator - JavaNCSS got an error while parsing the java file C:\project\src\main\java\Project\logging\LoggingAspect.aj
ParseException in STDIN
Last useful checkpoint: "project.logging."
Encountered "aspect" at line 4, column 17.
Was expecting one of:
    "@" ...
    "abstract" ...
    "final" ...
    "public" ...
    "synchronized" ...
    "strictfp" ...
    "class" ...
    "static" ...
    "protected" ...
    "private" ...
    "native" ...
    "transient" ...
    "volatile" ...
    "enum" ...
    "interface" ...


Javancss.(InputStream).e: net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.ParseException: Encountered "aspect" at line 6, column 17.
Was expecting one of:
    "@" ...
    "abstract" ...
    "final" ...
    "public" ...
    "synchronized" ...
    "strictfp" ...
    "class" ...
    "static" ...
    "protected" ...
    "private" ...
    "native" ...
    "transient" ...
    "volatile" ...
    "enum" ...
    "interface" ...

[cobertura] WARN  [main] net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.ComplexityCalculator - JavaNCSS got an error while parsing the java file C:\project\src\main\java\Project\logging\TracingAspect.aj
ParseException in STDIN
Last useful checkpoint: "project.logging."
Encountered "aspect" at line 6, column 17.
Was expecting one of:
    "@" ...
    "abstract" ...
    "final" ...
    "public" ...
    "synchronized" ...
    "strictfp" ...
    "class" ...
    "static" ...
    "protected" ...
    "private" ...
    "native" ...
    "transient" ...
    "volatile" ...
    "enum" ...
    "interface" ...


Report time: 3125ms

[INFO] Cobertura Report generation was successful.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 30 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 02 17:15:45 VET 2009
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/254M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: "Cobertura instrumentation is running before Aspectj weaving", are you using load-time weaving then?

Answer (score 2):

I have projects set up with aspectj-maven-plugin for compilation and using cobertura-maven-plugin for code coverage. For compile-time weaving this works fine when running `mvn site`, although the tests are compiled/run twice to allow for Cobertura weaving.

Running `mvn site` with the configuration below results in the following output:

```
[INFO] Preparing surefire-report:report
[INFO] [aspectj:compile {execution: compile_with_aspectj}]
...
[INFO] [compiler:compile]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
...
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: test-compile}]
[INFO] Compiling 8 source files to C:\test\aop-test
[INFO] [aspectj:test-compile {execution: test-compile_with_aspectj}]
...
[INFO] [surefire:test]
...
[INFO] Preparing cobertura:cobertura
[INFO] [aspectj:compile {execution: compile_with_aspectj}]
...
[INFO] [compiler:compile]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [cobertura:instrument]
[INFO] Cobertura 1.8 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
Instrumenting 11 files to C:\test\aop-test\generated-classes\cobertura
Cobertura: Saved information on 11 classes.
Instrument time: 250ms

[INFO] Instrumentation was successful.
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: test-compile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [aspectj:test-compile {execution: test-compile_with_aspectj}]
...
[INFO] [surefire:test]
...
Cobertura: Coverage data file C:\test\aop-test\cobertura.ser either 
    does not exist or is not readable.  Creating a new data file.
Cobertura: Saved information on 8 classes.
```

My configuration is included below.

Regarding the Cobertura warnings of your aspects, one thing you can try is moving the body of advice execution to java types rather than defining it in the aspects.

For example, rather than doing this:

```
before(Throwable e, Object subject): handlers(e, subject) {
    Log logger = getTraceLog(subject.getClass());

    //code to trace exception handling
    ...
}
```

Instead you can delegate the implementation to a Java type, so there is little code in the aspect to process:

```
before(Throwable e, Object subject): handlers(e, subject) {
    Log logger = getTraceLog(subject.getClass());

    //get helper type and delegate processing to that type.
    getFormatterHelper().traceErrorHandling(logger, thisJoinPoint, e);
}
```

My configuration for aspectj and cobertura plugins:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>compile_with_aspectj</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <complianceLevel>1.5</complianceLevel>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>test-compile_with_aspectj</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>test-compile</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <complianceLevel>1.5</complianceLevel>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
          <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
...
<reporting>
  <plugins>
  ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <formats>
          <format>html</format>
          <format>xml</format>
        </formats>
        <outputDirectory>target/site/cobertura</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  <plugins
</reporting>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem (trying to run a coverage reported on Hudson) and resolved it by removing the "test-compile" goal from the aspectj execution goals. After that both Cobertura and also Emma worked like a charm.

My AspectJ section:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
        <!-- <goal>test-compile</goal> --> 
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>  
    <source>1.6</source>  
    <weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder>true</weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder> 
    <weaveMainSourceFolder>true</weaveMainSourceFolder> 
  </configuration> 
</plugin>
```

My Cobertura section:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <configuration>
     <formats>
        <format>xml</format>
     </formats>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And just in case, my Emma section:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
</plugin>
```